# JTable JComboBox SetEditable not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, tablecelleditor

I am trying to get an editable `JComboBox` to work within a table but, so far, no luck.  Setting `cbo.setEditable(true)` seems to have no effect when operating within a cell within a table.  Is there something I am missing?  Please help.

Sample code to demonstrate the problem:

```
public class ComboBoxTest {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable table;
    private JComboBox<?> cboFrm = null;
    private JComboBox<?> cboTbl = null;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ComboBoxTest window = new ComboBoxTest();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ComboBoxTest() {
        initialise();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialise() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 455, 233);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        String[] cboData = { "tspn", "tblspn", "gram", "Kg" };

        cboFrm = new JComboBox<String>(cboData);
        cboFrm.setBounds(10, 26, 86, 20);
        cboFrm.setEditable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(cboFrm);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 57, 414, 127);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        String columnNames[] = { "Qty", "Measure", "Ingrediant" };
        // @formatter:off
        Object[][] tableData =
            {
                { 1, "Kg", "Sugar" },
                { 1, "pinch", "Salt" },
                { 2, "handfuls", "Peanuts" },
                { 1, "Litre", "Milk"}
            };
        // @formatter:on
        table = new JTable(tableData, columnNames);
        cboTbl = new JComboBox<String>(cboData);
        cboTbl.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                .setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cboTbl));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    }

}
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Works fine for me, can you describe your actual problem and your expectations...

Comment: Thanks for the responses.      What I am trying to do is to (say) add 'doggy' as a measure but when I move off the cell it reverts to 'Kg'.  I want it to stay as 'doggy'.  In other words, I don't want to be limited to only those items in the lookup.  Rather the combobox box list is most often used measures but not to limit the user to those options. 

Ray2U

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me with this output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

There seems to be a bug in the way JComboBox interacts with JTable.  The workaround is to press 'enter' after the new text has been altered. Tabbing off the table JComboBox cell doesn't work which is inconsistent with the behaviour of a standard text cell.

There is a bug report dating back to 1999-2001 where it was supposedly fixed but it has again resurfaced.  Refer to the following link:

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4275046